# Magento 2 : add pager in custom grid at frontend

Tags: magento2, pager, custom-grid

I have added one grid in customer account and getting collection also.But when I want to add pager in that grid, that time I am getting an error like :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.attribute_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.attribute_id) FROM `custommodule_test` AS `main_table` WHERE (customer_id='2') {"is_exception":false} []

Actually there is not any attribute_id filed is there in my table nor I am filtering for that filed name as you are seeing.

Please have a look :

test.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

block/test.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if ($this->getCollection()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'custom.collection.test'
        )->setCollection(
            $this->getCollection()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

public function getCollection()
{
    if (!$this->getData('collection')) {
        $this->setCollection(
            $this->_objectMangaer->get('Namespace\Modulename\Model\Test')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',2)
        );
    }
    return $this->getData('collection');
}
```

Please note : If I directly call

```
 $this->getCollection() ;
```

from phtml file then I got an correct collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fulfil the requirement, we have gone through many approaches and found the best solution for pagination on Magento2 custom collection. Here we are going to explain the best approach please follow the steps.

Note: Assuming that You have created a basic module in Magento2. Here Ipragmatech is our package and Ipreward is our module. Please, change your class name accordingly.

Step 1: Create a controller named Myrewad, action Index (Myreward/Index.php)and add the following code to execute method

```
<?php
  namespace Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Controller\Myreward;
  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
     {
        public function execute()
           {
               $this->_view->loadLayout();
               $this->_view->renderLayout();
           }
    }
```

Step 2: Create a block (Assuming that you have already created a model for your table. Here  We have custom table and we have created the model as reward) name Reward.php and add the following code. In this code, we have added the pager in our custom collection.

```
<?php
namespace Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Block\Myreward;

use Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Block\BaseBlock;

class Reward extends BaseBlock
  {
/**
 * @var \Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Model\Reward
 */
protected $_rewardCollection;

/**
 * Reward constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Model\Reward $rewardCollection
 */
public function __construct(
    \Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Block\Context $context,
    \Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Model\Reward $rewardCollection,
){
    $this->_rewardCollection = $rewardCollection;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{

    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Reward History'));

    if ($this->getRewardHistory()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'reward.history.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20))
            ->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->getRewardHistory()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getRewardHistory()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
/**
 * function to get rewards point transaction of customer
 *
 * @return reward transaction collection
 */
Public function getRewardHistory()
{
    //get values of current page
    $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
    $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest
    ()->getParam('limit') : 5;


    $collection = $this->_rewardCollection->getCollection();
    $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $collection->setCurPage($page);
    $logger->info("Here reward collection: ".$collection->getSelect());
    $logger->info("Here reward collection: Page:".$page." Page size :"
        .$pageSize);
    return $collection;
}
```

}
Step 3: Added/Modify the following code on layout file app/code/Ipragmatech/Ipreward/view/frontend/layout/ipreward_myreward_index.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">          
        <block class="Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Block\Myreward\Reward" name="myreward_reward" template="myreward/reward.phtml">
        </block>
       </referenceContainer>      
   </body>
 </page>
```

Step 4: Add your phtml file as app/code/Ipragmatech/Ipreward/view/frontend/templates/myreward/reward.phtml and add the following code

[image]

and the output will be look like this

[image]

Sometimes we have faced some CSS issue in which page limit not displayed so use the following CSS if you have the same issue.

```
 .custom-pager .limiter{
      display: block !important;
  }
```

Hope this will help you a lot. Please let us know if you have any issue regarding Magento customization.

Comment: please explain the step2. where to add that code? in Block file?

Comment: Myreward.php is file name for me, this code is complete code. Check namespace for the path

Comment: is it a Block file or Model file?

Comment: @jafar, Ipragmatech\Ipreward\Block\Myreward contains Block not model that mean its a block file.

Comment: What i need to use in place of this code
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'reward.history.pager'

reward.history.pager? I mean reward.history.pager is replaced by with which code?

Comment: reward.history.pager is replaced by with which code?

Answer (score 0):

for right count of pages and in toolbar like Items X to Y of Z total if pageSize e.g. = 10 just change this parameters like:

```
->setAvailableLimit([10 => 10])
```